# the input must be equal

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main (String[] args) {   
    int [] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int sum=0;
    int sum1=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
       for (int ii = 0 ; ii < i ; ii--){
           sum=sum+=numbers[i];                                            
       }
       System.out.println("The sum is " + sum  + " "+ sum1);
    } 

    System.out.print(" ");

}
```

the input must be equal for example is 
{1,2,3} if i group it into two the first result will be 1 != 5, and the second one is 3=3

Comment: Could you please post your expected output?

Comment: What input? you don't have much input here. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `sum=sum+=numers[i]` maybe you wanted to write `sum1=sum+=numbers[i]`? Though i would highly discourage this type of codestyle, since it does not promote clarity.

Comment: this is the expected output since there is no equal

The sums are 0 55

The sums are 1 54

The sums are 3 52

The sums are 6 49

The sums are 10 45

The sums are 15 40

The sums are 21 34

The sums are 28 27

The sums are 36 19

The sums are 45 10

Comment: "since there is no equal" - what do you mean by that?  Seriously, your problem statement is incomprehensible.   As such, your question is of little use to anyone ... apart from you ... and I have voted to close it.

Comment: You did not ask a question here.  All you did was post some code and scream "It doesn't work! Help!"  We don't do those kinds of "questions" here.  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

It looks (based on your example) like you wanted to group the input array into 2 sub-arrays and sum each of them separately, which is not what you did (you didn't add anything to your `sum1` variable).

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
       sum1+=numbers[j];                                           
    }
    for (int j = i; j < numbers.length; j++){
       sum2+=numbers[j];                                           
    } 
    System.out.println("The sums are " + sum1  + " "+ sum2);
}
```

For input array `{1,2,3}` you will get:

```
The sums are 0 6
The sums are 1 5
The sums are 3 3
```

If you want both groups to be non empty (so the first output line doesn't appear) you need to make a small change - start the outer loop with `int i = 1`.

Comment: this the one i was trying to do